# Dereferencing strings in preprocessor expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, c++14

My reading of the draft standard documents suggests that it should be legal to dereference a string literal, either with a unary * or with a constant subscript, in a preprocessor expression. For instance, I should be able to say (using the predefined __ DATE __ macro which expands to a quoted string):

```
#if *__DATE__ == 'A'
```

or

```
#if __DATE__[0] == 'A'
```

If I do this in GCC, with -std=gnu++0x, the former complains

```
error: operator '*' has no left operand
```

and the latter complains

```
error: token ""Feb 16 2016"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

The standards don't seem to define *constant-expression* any differently between the compiler and the preprocessor. The compiler happily compiles stuff like:

```
int foo[*__DATE__];
```

or

```
int foo[__DATE__[0]];
```

at global scope, proving that these are legitimate constant expressions.

I call foul. It seems to me that the standard *requires* the preprocessor to handle these types of expressions in #if or #elif clauses. Does anyone have any counterargument, before I go and report this as a GCC bug?

Comment: The problem is that a preprocessor processes text. In the preprocessor the `__DATE__` macro is replaced with "Feb 17 2016".

Comment: It's a defect of the standard, already reported as [CWG issue 1436](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1436).

Comment: Well, since that was from 2012, and the 2014 draft standard still hasn't resolved it, it's still arguable whether the defect is in the standard or the compiler. I see no reason why compiler preprocessors couldn't handle constructs like *"foo" or "foo"[2]. It's useful. I was trying to extract the year characters from the date macro, but one could also do hex conversions with "0123456789ABCDEF"[x] into a constant (something I frequently do in code).

Answer (score 0):

Your technique works in code, like an if (*_ _ DATE _ _ == 'A') statement, but not in an #IF macro.  The preprocessor won't do that sort of expression evaluation.